# ToolStripMenuItem can't show checkmark and Image (icon) when RenderMode is "System"?

Tags: c#, winforms

My Windows Forms application has a `MenuStrip` and some of the menu items (`ToolStripMenuItem`) have an icon (setting the `ToolStripMenuItem.Image` property).

When the `RenderMode` property of the `MenuStrip` is set to `ToolStripRenderMode.System`, the checkmark doesn't display when the `Checked` or `CheckOnClick` property is true and the menu item has an icon.

It **does** display when i switch the `MenuStrip.RenderMode` property to `ToolStripRenderMode.Professional` or `ToolStripRenderMode.RenderManagerMode`.

Unfortunately, this is a problem because my app requires:

1. A `ProgressBar` in marquee mode, so `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` is required to get this to work.
2. The app requires a "flat" visual style, which i accomplished by leaving out the call to `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` and leaving the default `ToolStripRenderMode.RenderManagerMode` on the MenuStrip.  But then i can't get my marquee ProgressBar!
3. Setting the `RenderMode` to `ToolStripRenderMode.System` solves the look and feel requirement, but takes away the ability to have checked menu items w/icons.

Is there any way to satisfy all my requirements?  Am i missing something?  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, i stumped SO!  Now i know i must be working on some serious code.

Anyway, the answer is: implement your own `ToolStripRenderer` by creating a class that inherits from `ToolStripSystemRenderer`.

Override the methods that draw the items with your own code.  Here's what i was looking for specifically that draws the checked item.  It draws a check if there's no image for the `ToolStripMenuItem`.

```
protected override void OnRenderItemCheck(ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRenderItemCheck(e);
    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(3, 1, 20, 20);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(4, 2, 18, 18);
        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(49, 106, 197));
        SolidBrush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, rect);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b2, rect2);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Image, new Point(5, 3));
    }
    else
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(3, 1, 20, 20);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(4, 2, 18, 18);
        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(49, 106, 197));
        SolidBrush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, rect);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b2, rect2);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Image, new Point(5, 3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did also come across a simpler alternative:

You can simply put your menu items into a ContextMenuStrip and then assign it to the **DropDown** property of the DropDownButton.

Hope this helps anyone out there who doesn't fancy overriding the Paint method.