# ToolStripControlHost with Icon and checkbox. How Hightlight selected item? Add Icon in Icon field?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, custom-controls, toolstripitem

I wanted to create `Custom ToolStripItem` that will have `checkbox` and Icon in it.
I menage to do that by creating  Custom Control with two `picturebox` and label.
Left `picturebox` if for icon and right is acting as special `checkbox` to add position to favorites.

I added that control to `ToolStripControlHost`.

1. The problem is the white spaces on left and right I wan't to remove them or move icon to left bar and remove right space. I tried to set `Padding` and `Margin` values to 0 but it doesn't work.
   I found post with similar problem but no were the correct answer. Is it possible to do that??

[image]

2. I want to make whole line highlight on MouseEnter just like normal elements  in ToolStripMenuItem. When I override OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave changing background proprieties it just change the color of hosted control not antirie ToolStripControlHost.
   Is it possible to simulate the same behavior as ToolStripMenuItem?

Right now it looks like Picture 'A' and I want it to look more like picture B but with star shape checkbox:

[image]

Basically i want to make My CustomToolStrip item as similar to ToolStripMenuItem as possible. With separate events for **Click (if you click on text)** and **ChackChange (if you Click on star)**

Any ideas how to do that?

That's part of My ToolStripControlHost Code:

```
    private void AddEvents()
    {
        this.ToolStripICItemControl.eMouseEnter += new EventHandler(On_MouseEnter);
        this.ToolStripICItemControl.eMouseLeave += new EventHandler(On_MouseLeave);
    }
    private void AutoSizeControl(Control control, int textPadding)
    {
        // Create a Graphics object for the Control.
        Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics();

        // Get the Size needed to accommodate the formatted Text.
        Size preferredSize = g.MeasureString(
           control.Text, control.Font).ToSize();

        // Pad the text and resize the control.
        this.Size = new Size(
           preferredSize.Width + 5 + 50 + (textPadding * 2),
           this.Size.Height /*+ (textPadding * 2)*/ );

        // Clean up the Graphics object.
        g.Dispose();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control c)
    {
        // Call the base so the base events are connected. 
        base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(c);

        // Cast the control to a  ToolStripCheckBox control.
        ToolStripImageAndCheckBox checkBoxToolStrip = (ToolStripImageAndCheckBox)c;

        // Add the event.
        checkBoxToolStrip.LabelClick += new EventHandler(checkBoxToolStrip_LabelClick);
        checkBoxToolStrip.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBoxToolStrip_CheckedChanged);
    }
    protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control c)
    {
        // Call the base method so the basic events are unsubscribed. 
        base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(c);

        // Cast the control to a ToolStripCheckBox control.
        ToolStripImageAndCheckBox checkBoxToolStrip = (ToolStripImageAndCheckBox)c;

        // Remove the event.
        checkBoxToolStrip.LabelClick -= new EventHandler(checkBoxToolStrip_LabelClick);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        DefaultBackColor = this.BackColor;
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        this.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
    }
    void checkBoxToolStrip_LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, e);
    }
    void checkBoxToolStrip_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckedChange != null)
            CheckedChange(this, e);
    }
    void On_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseLeave(e);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    void On_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Select();
        this.Focus();
        OnMouseEnter(e);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. If you want some complete code, you should describe what you want with some screen shot (like some sketch is enough). If you need some correction, you should post your code, show what's not satisfied with illustrative screen shot.

Comment: See [ToolStripMenuItem can't show checkmark and Image (icon) when RenderMode is “System”?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/710610/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech -thanks for link but that didn't help me because I don't know how to add new Render method to `ToolStripControlHost`
@KingKing - Thanks for your note I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: The link was to show how to create the menu item you described, which does not need to use a ToolStripControlHost nor a PictureBox.  BTW, the image you showed of how you want it to look does not include a CheckBox.

Comment: @LarsTech -Thanks for note I will update picture to better show what I  want to achieve.
I'm trying to implement this solution but I'm unable to move checked box to the left.
I updated how the control works in my post. I hope it will help to understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I menage to do what I needed by driving MyControl from ToolStripMenuItem and override onPaint method

```
public class MyControl : ToolStripMenuItem
{
    public MyControl(){}
    public MyControl(string text, Image image ):base (text,image){}
    public MyControl(string text):base(text){}
    public MyControl(Image image):base(image){}
    public MyControl(string text,Image image,EventHandler onClick):base(text,image,onClick){}
    public MyControl(string text, Image image,int id):base(text,image){  this.ID = id;}
    public MyControl(string text,Image image,int id,EventHandler onClick):base(text,image,onClick){this.ID = id; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (base.Checked == false)
        {
           Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.Width - 20, 1, 20, 20);               
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.BlackStar, rect);
        }
        else
        { 
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.Width - 20, 1, 20, 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.YellowStar, rect);
        }
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool StarClicked { get; set; }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        StarClicked = e.X > (this.Width - 20);
        if (StarClicked)
        {
            this.Checked = this.Checked == true ? false : true;
        }
        else
            base.OnClick(e);
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
```

that's how it looks right now

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwESK.png]

The form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddMenuElements(7);
    }
    public void AddMenuElements(int licznik)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem wszystkie = new ToolStripMenuItem("wszystkie", SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap());
        manu1ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(wszystkie);
        menuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripSystemRenderer();
        for (int i = 0; i < licznik; i++)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem element = new ToolStripMenuItem(String.Format("element {0}", i), GetIcon(i),element2_Click);
            element.Visible = i % 2 == 0 ? false:true;                
            manu1ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(element);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < licznik; i++)
        {
            MyControl element2 = new MyControl(String.Format("element {0}",i), GetIcon(i),element2_Click);
            element2.ID = i;
            element2.CheckedChanged += (s, e) =>
            {                    
                MyControl control = s as MyControl;
                manu1ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[control.ID + 1].Visible = control.Checked;                  
            };
            element2.Checked = i % 2 == 0 ? false : true;

            wszystkie.DropDownItems.Add(element2); 

        }
    }
    void element2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl kontener = (sender as MyControl);

        if (kontener.ForeColor == Color.Red)
            kontener.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        else
            kontener.ForeColor = Color.Red;

    }
    private static Image GetIcon(int i)
    {
        Image ikona = null;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: ikona = SystemIcons.Application.ToBitmap();
                break;
            case 1: ikona = SystemIcons.Asterisk.ToBitmap();
                break;
            case 2: ikona = SystemIcons.WinLogo.ToBitmap();
                break;
            case 3: ikona = SystemIcons.Exclamation.ToBitmap();
                break;
            case 4: ikona = SystemIcons.Hand.ToBitmap();
                break;
            case 5: ikona = SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
                break;
            default: ikona = SystemIcons.Shield.ToBitmap();
                break;
        }
        return ikona;
    }   
}
```

Basically it does What I want I just need to stop it from disappearing when clicked on star.
Thanks for Help @LarsTech it gave me a hint how to do that.